# A strange issue with Address Book programming guide for iOS documentation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, casting

I am at a beginner level of iOS programming. I am using Xcode 4.2 with iOS Simulator 5.0. 
I am making the quick start tutorial app using iOS documentation [Address Book programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html) and I'm following all the steps of the tutorial but I get a strange error in this code:

```
-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    NSString *name;
    name = (NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    self.firstName.text=name;

    name=( NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    self.lastName.text=name;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

at line:

```
name = (NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

I get the error `Cast of C pointer type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') to Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' requires a bridged cast`

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1) which has been updated with the latest:

```
NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                           kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

or

```
NSString* name = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                           kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```